# Fit 2 TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to fit 2 TextViews in one line. I tried to use LinearLayout, and now my best approach is to use RelativeLayout.
Here you can see XML for it

```
       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/partner_full_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/session_duration"
            android:text="@string/dummy_text" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/session_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="asdadsd"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And the result

[image: Result]

As you can see it's fit's okay, but second TextView is on the right side, when I want it to be after first TextView.
When I used LinearLayout I faced problem with size of first TextView (if it have to many text in it, second TextView will go off screen). Another approach with LinearLayout gave me similar results to RelativeLayout with same problem (wrong position of second view)

Comment: use weightsum..

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` Remove this.

Comment: @SatanPandeya if I remove it second TextView will move to the left(to the left of parent view)

Comment: Then, add `android:layout_below=id/previousOne ` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are using `wrap_content`. If `textView1` needs the space of the whole screen, then `textView2` will get nothing. Instead you can use `layout_weight` to always give a View his space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/partner_full_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Super Long String"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/session_duration"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="I will always show"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So, used it for a while and faced problem. You see, when TextView1(partner_full_name) text is small - all ok. But when it's bigger than  half of view it's getting forced to 2nd line although there is plenty of space ahead (TextView2 text is small in most cases) and in result I have really weird view.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from second TextView :

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```